# @Around Aspect is Executing before @transaction Annotation Spring

Tags: java, transactions, aop, spring-aop, aspect

I have one class with transaction Annotation:

```java
@Service
@EnableTransactionManagement(order=2000)
public class UserManagementServiceImpl implements UserManagementService {
    @Transactional
    public User addUser(User user) throws AlreadyExistException {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I have one Aspect class:

```java
@Component
@Aspect
public class PublisherAspect {
    @Around("execution(* com.toi.expresso.service.UserManagementService.addUser(..))")
    public User publishAddUserEvent(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

my `@Around` Annotation is getting executed before `addUser` save the data in Database. Please suggest me how `@Around` will execute after data save in database.

Answer (score 0):

The interesting part of your aspect is the `...`, i.e. the advice body. Assuming that your `addUser` method really returns a `User` and not `void` (which I would expect) or anything else, you can narrow down the pointcut to methods actually having a `User` return type so as to avoid problems with methods returning other types.

```java
@Component
@Aspect
public class PublisherAspect {
    @Around("execution(User com.toi.expresso.service.UserManagementService.addUser(..))")
    public User publishAddUserEvent(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) {
        // Do something before method execution
        User user = jp.proceed();
        // Do something after method execution
        return user;
    }
}
```

The more generic solution if you want to match all return types:

```java
@Component
@Aspect
public class PublisherAspect {
    @Around("execution(* com.toi.expresso.service.UserManagementService.addUser(..))")
    public Object publishAddUserEvent(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) {
        // Do something before method execution
        Object result = jp.proceed();
        // Do something after method execution
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes  `'adduser'` is returning User object. but just after holding user object if I am checking database for the same user its returning empty set.

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class PublisherAspect {
    @Around("execution(User com.toi.expresso.service.UserManagementService.addUser(..))")
    public User publishAddUserEvent(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) 
       {
          // Do something before method execution
          User user = jp.proceed();
           //checking in database(Sending message to other application but that application didn't find user in same db)
            return user;
        }
    }
}
```